# \def a variable for sqrt with parameters

Tags: calculations

I tried to define variables with the sqrt command but couldn't get the result printed .

```
\def \radius {sqrt(4^2+2^2)}
\draw (4,3) node [right] {$The radius is \radius for x=4, y=2$};
```

The \draw shows "Theradiusissqrt(4^2+2^2)forx=4,y=2" instead of
"The radius is 4.47 for  x=4, y=2".

Also, I tried to \def the variable with pass-ins like below:

```
\def \my_radius#1#2 {sqrt(#1^2+#2^2)}   % r=4.47
\draw (4,0) node [right] {$My_radius is \my_radius{4}{2}\ for x=4, y=2$};
```

It didn't show the result. What would be the right code for these two examples?
Btw, I am using the TeXnicCenter IDE, how do I debug/print by not using \draw?

Comment: It wouldn't have solved all of your problems, but `_` generally has a special character code, and shouldn't be in a command name.  Also, once you start math with `$`, everything is math.  So `$The radius is...` is the variable T, times h, times e, times r, times a, times d, ....  Notice how in wipet's answer, only the math is in `$`, the text is not.

Comment: I tried simpler way `\def \radius {$(4^2+2^2)^(0.5)$)}` without sqrt(), but the \draw is still missing the numerical result. It prints out \radius as the formula, no evaluation? I got the idea from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66216/draw-arc-in-tikz-when-center-of-circle-is-specified).

Comment: You tagged this question with [tag:tikz-pgf] even though, it has nothing to do with it. If you wanted to use PGFMath for the evaluation, simply use `\pgfmathprint{\radius}` but this won't have good precision. The result will never show on its own, if you just use `\radius` , it will always just expand to the replacement text you specified.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `apnum` package for evaluating expressions. The following example is in plain TeX:

```
\input tikz
\input apnum

\apFRAC=2
\evaldef\radius{\SQRT{4^2+2^2}}

\tikzpicture
\draw (4,0) node [right] {The radius is \radius\ for $x=4, y=2$};
\endtikzpicture

\bye
```

In OpTeX, you can use `\expr` macro, which evaluates the expression by Lua.

```
\edef\radius{\expr[2]{math.sqrt(4^2+2^2)}}

The radius is \radius\ for $x=4, y=2$.

\bye
```

You can use "variables" `\x` and `\y` with variable values too:

```
\def\my_radius{\expr[2]{math.sqrt(\x^2+\y^2)}}

\def\x{4} \def\y{2}
The radius is \my_radius\ for $x=\x, y=\y$.
% prints: The radius is 4.47 for x = 4, y = 2.

\def\x{7} \def\y{1}
The radius is \my_radius\ for $x=\x, y=\y$.
% prints: The radius is 7.07 for x = 7, y = 1.

\bye
```

Note that OpTeX allows to define the control sequence `\my_radius` directly. On the other hand, if you say `\def\my_radius` in LaTeX, then you define a macro `\my` with obligatory separator `_radius`. It isn't what you want.

Comment: I have a hard time to get my math expression like `\def \radius {$(4^2+2^2)^(0.5)$)}` evaluated. How do I insert \expr to `\def \radius {(4^2+2^2)^(0.5)}`? Any manuals on \expr and math.sqrt? what packages are needed?

Comment: @LeonChang `\expr` is macro from OpTeX and you needn't any package. Note, that OpTeX is not LaTeX. If you are asking to LaTeX packages then I am unable to help you, because I don't using LaTeX. Your question didn't specify that you need a LaTeX solution.

Answer (score 3):

With `expl3`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \radius { m m }{
    The~radius~is~  
    $\fp_eval:n {round(sqrt(#1^2+#2^2),2)}$~
    for~$x=#1$,~$y=#2$
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (4,3) node [right] {\radius{4}{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `pgf`, in the `pgfmanual` documentation section 94.3.8 Miscellaneous functions

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (4,3) node [right] {The radius is $\pgfmathparse{veclen(4,2)}\pgfmathresult$ for $x=4$, $y=2$ };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For this case, I wouldn’t use `\ExplSyntaxOn`, but just `\fpeval` in the body.

Comment: The [round off](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598536/pgfmath-rounded-number-without-pgfmathprintnumber) version for `pgfmathprint` is `pgfmathprintnumber[precision]` like `\def \myRadius#1#2 {\pgfmathparse{sqrt((#1)^2+(#2)^2)}\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}};`

Answer (score 3):

With LaTeX released October 2023, you can define your own function for `\fpeval` calculations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new_function:n { pythadd }
\fp_set_function:nnn { pythadd } { a,b } { sqrt(a^2+b^2) }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\radius}[2]{%
  The radius is $\fpeval{round(pythadd(#1,#2),2)}$
  for $x=#1$ and $y=#2$%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=\fpeval{pythadd(4,2)}mm];
  \draw (1,0) node [right] {\radius{4}{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With previous releases you can do the same with a macro

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\pythadd}[2]{sqrt((#1)^2+(#2)^2)}

\newcommand{\radius}[2]{%
  The radius is $\fpeval{round(\pythadd{#1}{#2},2)}$
  for $x=#1$ and $y=#2$%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) circle [radius=\fpeval{\pythadd{4}{2}}mm];
  \draw (1,0) node [right] {\radius{4}{2}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One question about \fpeval. It seems that \fpeval doesn't work with \def but works with \newcommand? e.g. `\def \myRadius#1#2 {\pgfmathprint{sqrt((#1)^2+(#2)^2)}}; \draw (3,-5) node [right] {My fpev radius is \fpeval{round(\myRadius{4}{2},3)}` encountered errors. Even `\fpeval{round(\radius2,7)}` only prints out 7?

Comment: @LeonChang `\pgfmathprint` is not expandable, so it cannot be used inside `\fpeval`

Comment: So can we say what `\def` macros does to `\pgfmathprint` is what `\newcommand` to `\fpeval`? On-line says >\def is a TeX primitive, \newcommand is a LaTeX overlay on top of \def >unless you want something that \newcommand can't do, there's no point in reinventing the wheel [with \def].

Comment: @LeonChang sorry, but I don’t understand your point